# Create Google Container Cluster with custom kubernetes version

Tags: google-cloud-platform, coreos, kubernetes

I'm trying to use Google cluster container and faced very odd issue. Google preinstalls and preconfigures kubernetes+coreos in this cluster. It has version 0.12.2 and looks like it's buggy:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/5920#issuecomment-86205610

Is there a way to install newer version of kubernetes during cluster creation?

Comment: this question was answered in github issue.

Answer (score 2):

Answering here as well, since we resolved this [on github as well](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/5920):

> Unfortunately that is a known issue with 0.12.2 on GKE that we found
>   shortly after making it available. We've since pulled that release
>   from GKE but clusters that are still running it won't be able to
>   create external load balancers.
>
> Your best bet is to create a new cluster (the default is now 0.13.2)
>   which has this bug fixed.

And if you need to fall back to an older version:

> You can choose the cluster version on the command line with
>   --cluster-api-version:
>
> https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/container/clusters/create
>
> We have a downlevel version available (usually). Also, 0.13.2 is
>   default as of yesterday afternoon, and because of this issue, 0.11.0
>   remains our downlevel version.

(FWIW, if you're interested in assistance from the Kubernetes team, we obviously monitor github actively, we pay attention to Stack Overflow under the "kubernetes" tag, and of course you're welcome to join the #google-containers IRC channel on freenode.)